# Array of Boolean As Checkbox Value?

Tags: react-native

I have a statu structure array that is called 'devices'. It has ID (item ID), name (item name), renew (string value from DDL), and **check (boolean value, whether the checkbox is checked or not)**

These information will be displayed as items one by one.

While I don't have problem displaying name and ID, My problem is actually on both renew and check, but I want to solve check first.

I have tried the following on the checkbox:

```
            <CheckBox 
            checked={item.check}
            onPress ={ () =>{
              if (item.check === false){
                item.check = true
              }
              else {
                item.check = false
              }
            }}
            />
```

(I use **item** instead of **this.state.devices**, because i mapped the array)

This one is where i created devices:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      devices: [
  {
    check: false,
    name: 'PHONE',
    id: '01658',
    renew: '',
  },
  {
    check: false,
    name: 'PHONE',
    id: '04523',
    renew: ''
  },
  {
    check: false,
    name: 'LAPTOP',
    id: '04451',
    renew: ''
  },
  {
    check: false,
    name: 'PHONE',
    id: '01165',
    renew: ''
  },
  {
    check: false,
    name: 'TABLET',
    id: '01015',
    renew: ''
  },
  ]
    };
  }
```

This is where the array map start and where I made the checkbox:

```
  render() {
    return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.devices.map((item, index) => {
          console.log("start");
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <View style={styles.itemRow}>

                  <View style={styles.itemCell}>
                    <CheckBox 
                    checked={item.check}
                    onPress ={ () =>{
                      if (item.check === false){
                        item.check = true
                      }
                      else {
                        item.check = false
                      }
                    }}
                    />
                  </View>
```

I expected the checkbox to change its value when pressed, and then the boolean value will be written on item.check of the respective index. What happened are either the checkbox value changed all at once as a group; or the value wont change at all.

Comment: You have to update devices array in state else it won't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a setState to update the checkbox. For example, you could do something like:

```
onPress={()=>this.handleCheck(item.id}
```

where handleCheck is:

```
handleCheck = (id) => {
    let tempArr = this.state.devices
    let updatedArr=tempArr.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
            item.check = !item.check
            return item
        }
        return item
    })
    this.setState({devices:updatedArr})
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me either. (The checkboxes doesn't change)

Comment: Updated my question! forgot to put the new devices Array in a variable